# CakePHP: Scaffolding after having written edit/view/add

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, scaffolding

I have an application in which we give a very friendly interface for managing data. This is done through many controllers' add/edit/view functions. But now the requirement has come that we should have "super admins" able to edit anything, and scaffolding will give them a quick and dirty manner of changing data. Since scaffolding uses add/edit/view by default, I've unintentionally overwritten the ability to scaffold.

I can't just go and change all my calls to edit/add for our "user friendly" data managing. So I want to essentially ignore the add/edit/view when, for example, a user has a flag of "yes, please let me scaffold". I imagined it would be something like:

```
    public function edit($id) {
        if (admin_user) {        
            $scaffold;
        } else {
            [user-friendly version code]
        }
    }
```

But no dice. How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: maybe [this page of the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/scaffolding.html#creating-a-simple-admin-interface-with-scaffolding) is what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I've already read the page. :( I admit it is a bit confusing, but I am not making anything (I think?) with Admin. What I need is really for most controllers in the system, and I'm not sure what routing even has to do with what I want to achieve.

Comment: If a user is flagged as admin you can redirect him to the admin view/edit/add. `if(admin_user) redirect(array('action' => 'admin_edit'))`. You can do this in your app_controller `beforeFilter` so it will apply to all your actions. Then you use admin scaffold as seen in the manual

Comment: Is there a way to do this for anything? Like define $scaffold = 'scaf' and then all my scaffolding will go to scaf_edit. I tried that but it does not work. An "admin" in this system is not necessarily a cakephp "admin".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you already have admin users and you want to scaffold only super-user:

Also suppose you store the information about beeing a super-user or not in a column named `super` in the `users` table

in your core.php

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin', 'super));
```

in your appController

```
public $scaffold = 'super';

beforFilter() {
    if($this->Auth->user('super') && !isset($this->params['super'])
        $this->redirect(array('super' => true));
}
```

Now I can't try this code but the idea should work.

edit: we need to check if we are already in a super_action to avoid infinite redirect

Comment: Perfect! I understand now. Thanks so much. I have scaffolding working with a url such as: site.com/scaff/controller/add. I put $scaffolding = 'scaff'; in my AppController. I didn't have to create any special views or actions. Thanks so much.